# How to override Recycler.View adapter abstract methods with a nullable returned value?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, overriding

I'm working on a *RecyclerView*.
I'm writing a class that extends *RecyclerView.Adpater*  and I'm overriding the *Adapter* abstract methods.
It is possible that the list I'm working with is null.
So I want the following  method:

```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int
```

to return **Int?** instead of Int, but now the compiler tells me that I'm returning a wrong return type.
So what can I do, if I want to enable a nullable list and still extend RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: why not return 0?

Comment: I'm not familiar with kotlin, but in java it would be something like: ```@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int itemCount = super.getItemCount();
        return itemCount == 0 ? 0 : itemCount ;
    }``` Hope you can convert to kt.

Comment: @Prince Ali , I didn't find a method getItemCount when writing super

Comment: I mentioned that this was in java. Since this class is abstract you must extend another class that extends the RecyclerView.adapter and override the getItemCount()...

Comment: ok thanks. i think that somewhere you should have a null check on java code

Comment: Anyway, like Tuqay said more info is needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int{
    return myList?.size ?: 0
}
```

Further simplified:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = myList?.size ?: 0
```

Edit: For future readers, OP has changed the question. We discussed it a little bit in comments

Comment: I  have edited the post(the  function that I'm overriding is getItemViewType). it this situation what should i return as elvis operator? the value -1?

Comment: Why do you need that method?

Comment: I mean, if you want to add some logic to it, then you should share that code with us

Comment: because i have a lot of different types that the recycler view can display. But i think your answer is enough, and i should work with elvis operator

Comment: you know, `getItemViewType` depends on the position and you don't really need to care if your list is null, because position will be provided by adapter and if it is 0, then this method won't even be called

Comment: so just to return a value like -1 because it will never happen?

Comment: Yes you can do that. To be honest I haven't faced this kind of problem. If you don't override that method it returns 0 by default and I would recommend returning 0 in that case